# The export 'XYZ.IMessageCenterBL (ContractName="XYZ.IMessageCenterBL")' is not assignable to type 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult'

Tags: c#, mef

Unlike other questions on the topic of export not being of certain type, this one is completely different.

The types `XYZ.IMessageCenterBL` and `System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult` are completely and utterly different - there is no way we could confuse them.

Moreover, the code would not compile if I would try to use `System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult` instead of `XYZ.IMessageCenterBL`.

Right now `XYZ.IMessageCenterBL` is injected into a property:

```
[Import]
public IMessageCenterBL MessageCenterBL { get; set; }
```

Notice, how there is no place for any confusion - where does this `JsonResult` business come from?

Also, if I move the dependency from the property into the constructor (i.e. `IMessageCenterBL` is injected into the constructor and the property is set explicitly from there) it starts to work!

Here is the entire MEF exception output:

```
Unhandled Exception at url: http://localhost:51000/u/2s4xYN1VikulrQAi44nvWg/Framework/XmlForm/GetTemplate 
System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'DF.Web.Framework.Controllers.XmlForms.XmlFormController`1[DF.Data.WorkFlow.WF_Employee]'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor. ---> System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException: The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.

1) The export 'DF.Web.Framework.Business.IMessageCenterBL (ContractName="DF.Web.Framework.Business.IMessageCenterBL")' is not assignable to type 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult'.

Resulting in: Cannot set import 'DF.Web.Platform.DFController.Data (ContractName="DF.Web.Framework.Business.IMessageCenterBL")' on part 'DF.Web.Framework.Controllers.XmlForms.XmlFormController(DF.Data.WorkFlow.WF_Employee)'.
Element: DF.Web.Platform.DFController.Data (ContractName="DF.Web.Framework.Business.IMessageCenterBL") -->  DF.Web.Framework.Controllers.XmlForms.XmlFormController({0}) -->  AssemblyCatalog (Assembly="DF.Web.Framework, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b3dac0a0872f0a93")

Resulting in: Cannot get export 'DF.Web.Framework.Controllers.XmlForms.XmlFormController(DF.Data.WorkFlow.WF_Employee) (ContractName="DF.Web.Framework.Controllers.XmlForms.XmlFormController(DF.Data.WorkFlow.WF_Employee)")' from part 'DF.Web.Framework.Controllers.XmlForms.XmlFormController(DF.Data.WorkFlow.WF_Employee)'.
Element: DF.Web.Framework.Controllers.XmlForms.XmlFormController(DF.Data.WorkFlow.WF_Employee) (ContractName="DF.Web.Framework.Controllers.XmlForms.XmlFormController(DF.Data.WorkFlow.WF_Employee)") -->  DF.Web.Framework.Controllers.XmlForms.XmlFormController({0}) -->  AssemblyCatalog (Assembly="DF.Web.Framework, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b3dac0a0872f0a93")

   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionServices.GetExportedValueFromComposedPart(ImportEngine engine, ComposablePart part, ExportDefinition definition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.GetExportedValue(CatalogPart part, ExportDefinition export, Boolean isSharedPart)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.CatalogExport.GetExportedValueCore()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export.get_Value()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.GetCastedExportedValue[T](Export export)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.ExportFactoryCreator.LifetimeContext.GetExportLifetimeContextFromExport[T](Export export)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.ExportFactoryCreator.<>c__DisplayClass4`1.<CreateStronglyTypedExportFactoryOfT>b__3()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportFactory`1.CreateExport()
   at DF.Web.Platform.MefDependencyResolver.CacheItem`1.GetService(CompositionContainer compositionContainer) in c:\DF\SharpTop\UI\Platform\MefDependencyResolver.cs:line 41
   at DF.Web.Platform.MefDependencyResolver.System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver.GetService(Type serviceType) in c:\DF\SharpTop\UI\Platform\MefDependencyResolver.cs:line 100
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

How can MEF confuse those two types?

Answer (score 0):

I just retested the whole issue now and it works OK. Knowing it was reproduced on two computers by two independent developers, I have no explanation to this strange behavior...